# placing SQL order by (simple)

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I'm trying to order the following results on reference. Using Order by and desc limit 100. Can someone help me where to place it.

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `reference`, SUM( `stockdifference` ) AS 'stockdifference'  
FROM `results1` 
WHERE `datum` BETWEEN '".$oldDate."' AND '".$newDate."' AND `reference` = '".$stm[0]."'");
```

Comment: After the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Do `GROUP BY reference` as well, after WHERE and before ORDER BY.

Comment: did you not read any of the MySQL manuals?

Comment: comment repost: there's nothing here "to" prepare since there's no placeholders in your query. So just do `query` instead of `prepare`.

Answer (score 0):

To order a sql query is simple.

```
Select *
FROM table
Where column=condition
ORDER BY column desc/asc
Limit
```

Comment: are you sure he is asking about the SQL syntax and not about how to write the PDO parameters?

Answer (score -1):

try :

```
<?php 
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `reference`, SUM( `stockdifference` ) AS 'stockdifference'  
FROM `results1` 
WHERE `datum` BETWEEN '".$oldDate."' AND '".$newDate."' AND `reference` = '".$stm[0]."'
Order by 'your column',
'your column' desc,
limit 100

");
```

Comment: what exactly are you preparing ? Where are the parameters?